# How to get First in and Last out in multiple records with night shift:

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have Date, Time, EmpId, InOut,  Shift_Start_Time and Shift_End_Time of an employee.

Need your help to write a sql for these conditions:
1.Consider the records which Time is falling between Shift_Start_Time and Shift_End_Time. If the In/Out time is outside the shift_start & Shift_End time, ignore them.
 Ex:Shift_Start_Time is 18:00:00 and Shift_End_Time is 07:00:00. If my In time is before 18:00 or Out time is after 07:00, no need to consider.

2. Take first IN and Last OUT between Shift_Start and Shift_End time window.
   Note:Here Date will change for night shift. Ex: First IN time is 18:30 on 03/04/2020 and OUT time is 06:30 on 03/05/2020
3. If it is day shift, simply take first IN and last OUT time of an emp and this time should be between Shift_Start and Shift_End time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT *
FROM sampledata
WHERE `Time` + CASE WHEN Shift_Start_Time > Shift_End_Time
                                           THEN '24:00'
                                           ELSE '00:00'
                                           END 
      BETWEEN Shift_Start_Time 
          AND Shift_End_Time + CASE WHEN Shift_Start_Time > Shift_End_Time
                                    THEN '24:00'
                                    ELSE '00:00'
                                    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing as datetime rather than using separate date and time fields? This would make the issue of the night shift occurring over two days a lot more manageable